# symfony 3 - how to allow unauthenticated access to a URL prefix

Tags: php, symfony

Symfony 3.0.3 I want to exclude URLs starting with `/document` from having to log in

My current `security.yml` firewalls:

```
  firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    docs:
        pattern: ^/document
        security: false            

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider

        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /
            check_path: login

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: true
```

But this results in Error 500 : "The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL." when visiting `/document`

Answer (score 1):

How is your `access_control` configuration in `security.yml`. Shouldn't you allow `/document` for `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`?

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/document$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

In this case, you don't have to define a separate `firewall` for `/document`.

Comment: if I add that and remove the `docs` firewall, I get challenged for a login when I navigate to `/document` urls

Comment: It shouldn't unless you have added some extra authentication validation in controller or somewhere else. Can you provide Controller information which `/document` route is targeting to?